# Pandas: efficient way to transform DataFrame layout in one step without loops

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Ottawa City Council','City of Toronto'], columns = ['Entity'])
```

How can I change the layout of df to look as below in one step? I know I can do it with loops but I'm seeking the most efficient way as I have 1.2 million rows so it will take hours. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create the new column, for now with a list of words:

```
df['Word'] = df.Entity.str.split(' ')
```

Then explode it (a new function in *Pandas* version *0.25*):

```
df.explode('Word')
```

Answer (score 1):

df['Word'] = [x.split() for x in df.Entity]
df.explode('Word') # pandas >= 25.0